# Cloudinary giving error "Cloud name must be specified in Account!" in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, cloudinary

Basically, at this line 43, I'm getting the error `Cloud name must be specified in Account!`

`Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Cloud name must be specified in Account!`

```
Line 42:             var myAccount = new Account { Cloud = _cloud, ApiKey= _apiKey, ApiSecret = _apiSecret};
Line 43:             Cloudinary _cloudinary = new Cloudinary(myAccount);
```

This is my complete image upload function

```
 public string ImageUploadFunc(HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {
            
            string _apiKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CloudinaryAPIKey"];
            string _apiSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CloudinarySecretKey"];
            string _cloud = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CloudinaryAccount"];
            string uploadedImageUrl = string.Empty;
            
            var myAccount = new Account { Cloud = _cloud, ApiKey= _apiKey, ApiSecret = _apiSecret};
            Cloudinary _cloudinary = new Cloudinary(myAccount);


           
                var uploadParams = new ImageUploadParams()
                {
                    File = new FileDescription(file.FileName, file.InputStream)
                };
                var uploadResult = _cloudinary.Upload(uploadParams);
                uploadedImageUrl = uploadResult?.SecureUri?.AbsoluteUri;

                return uploadedImageUrl;

        }
```

The environment variables in WebConfig file are correctly setup:

```
<add key="CloudinaryAccount" value="cloudName" />
<add key="CloudinaryAPIKey" value="sampleapikey" />
<add key="CloudinarySecretKey" value="samplesecretkey" />
```

I don't get what the problem is as everything seems to be set up. Please help if anyone knows regarding this issue.

Comment: it looks like the value of _apiKey, _apiSecret, and _cloud are as if they are empty string. Can you try to output those values to verify it's showing the correct values?

Comment: Yes you are right. The values were not being printed meaning they were empty so I now initialized the values directly in the function and the picture is being uploaded now. Thank you so much. But, do you know why the environment variables are not being set up properly?

Answer (score 0):

Hei. I had the same error. The problem was that i messed up something in my github repository and had to clone the project.

But i had gitignore on my appsetting.json and that file didn't transfer with the clone because it never was in the repository.

If you run the debugger and add a breakpoint here:
string _cloud = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CloudinaryAccount"];
value it will probably be null.

I hope it makes sense.